# How to implement "Find and Replace" logic in Handsontable?

Tags: javascript, replace, find, spreadsheet, handsontable

As we have find and replace logic in Excel and many other documents, how to implement the same using Handsontable? I tried to find the same in the Handsontable site but could not find. All i could find was "search" using searchbox.

Im new to Handsontable. Any help on this would be great.

Comment: I'm afraid you will have to create a replace function yourself. I never heard of any "replace" function as you describe it yet. Did you try anything so far ? I will try to find the time to create one on my side as it can be very useful and share.

Comment: Im looking for something like we get a dialog box in excel/eclipse/notepad or any other documents to find and replace texts.

Answer (score 0):

You can easily reuse the search function already present in the [Handsontable documentation example](https://docs.handsontable.com/2.0.0/demo-searching.html#page-custom-query-method) for the first part of the problem.

You then have to add a field where you can put the value you want to replace the cells that have been match, and use the below simple function to replace those values by the new one :

```
Handsontable.dom.addEvent(Replace, 'click', function() {
  // Replace the value of every cell that have been match by the search query
  for (row = 0, r_len = queryResult.length; row < r_len; row++) {
    hot.setDataAtCell(queryResult[row].row, queryResult[row].col, replace);
  }
  // Reset all the fields
  SearchField="";
  ReplaceField="";
  queryResult="";
  document.getElementById('Search').value='';
  document.getElementById('ReplaceWith').value='';
});
```

See this working [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/osdu7wcs/) example.

Answer (score 0):

Adding to https://stackoverflow.com/a/50228873/9230481

Note that this fail if you enable any form of sorting or filtering (e.g. `columnSorting: true`) because the matches in „visual indices“, which change after sorting. To solve this you need map the indices to physical ones right after the search finished. See https://handsontable.com/docs/api/core/#tophysicalrow and https://handsontable.com/docs/api/core/#tophysicalcolumn

In the replace function you need to map physical indices back to visual indices as `setDataAtCell` expects visual indices: https://handsontable.com/docs/api/core/#setdataatcell